# Trying to use jQuery to display JSON text data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know very little (none) JavaScript, or much about using API's.  However I would like to display some hotel reviews on my webiste made available over the qype.com API.  However I'm struggling with being able to manage this.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $.getJSON( "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=hilton%20metropole&location=B26%203QJ&ywsid=APIKEY Removed",
    function(data) {
      $.each( data.businesses, function(i,businesses) {
        content = '<p>' + businesses.reviews.text_excerpt + '</p>';
        content = '<p>' + businesses.reviews.date + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#review");
      } );
    }
  );
} );
```

I have a div in the body called review where I want to display the text.

Any advice greatly received.

JSON can be found at http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=hilton%20metropole&location=B26%203QJ&ywsid=lOoGGbkYpVmTvxHlWGT2Lw

Also, I have multiple businesses on the same page, how would I make use of this multiple times on the same page, but output the data in different locations?

Comment: Now having added &callback=? to the end of the URL, I see the text 'undefined' in my page.  I guess this means I', not pointing to the correct part of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Ah, I see your error now. `businesses.reviews` is an array (each business can have more than one review) so you have to loop over each business and each business' reviews.

*i had to change some things to get it to run in my test bed, but you can see a sample of this code running here: http://bit.ly/4mTxPp*

yelp currently support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) calls so you can change your code to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
function showData(data) {
    $.each(data.businesses, function(i,business){
        // extra loop
        $.each(business.reviews, function(i,review){ 
            var content = '<p>' + review.text_excerpt + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' +review.date + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo('#review');
        });
    });      
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    // note the use of the "callback" parameter
    writeScriptTag( "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?"+
    "term=hilton%20metropole"+
    "&location=B26%203QJ"+
    "&ywsid=lOoGGbkYpVmTvxHlWGT2Lw"+
    "&callback=showData"); // <- callback
});

function writeScriptTag(path) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", path);

    document.body.appendChild(fileref);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would be great if Yelp had a public jsonp API to test out fesibility of certain things.

Comment: Nice script - why do you write out the script tags? Is there an advantage of doing that

Answer (score 2):

Do you get an error in Firebug using this code? What happens exactly?

I expect this problem is caused by the fact that you're trying to do a cross-domain request which is not allowed. Normally you'll want to do this kind of data gathering on your back-end, but you can use an alternative such as JSONP to do the same.

Take a look at jQuery's [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) on this stuff and it should be clear what's going on.

Also, as a side note: In your callback you have `content =` which is ok but not ideal. Assigning to `content` like this will create a variable in the global scope which you do not want. In this case it probably wont cause an issue but say you have 2 of these requests going at once, the second assignment could easily step on the first causing hard-to-debug weirdness. Best to just always create variables with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

If `data.businesses` is an array, I would assume that `data.businesses[x].reviews` is also an array.  This code loops the businesses as well as the reviews for each business.  It also gets rid of the `content` variable by appending straight to the `#review` div.

```
$.each(data.businesses, function(i,business){
    $.each(business.reveiws, function(r,review){
        $("#review").append(
         '<p>' + review.text_excerpt + '</p>'
        ).append(
         '<p>' + review.date + '</p>'
        );
   });
});
```

I think you can specify JSONP with your `$.getJSON` method by adding "callback=?" to the url parameters.

> As of jQuery 1.2, you can load JSON
>   data located on another domain if you
>   specify a JSONP callback, which can be
>   done like so: "myurl?callback=?"

```
$.getJSON("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=hilton%20metropole&location=B26%203QJ&ywsid=APIKEY Removed&callback=?",
  function(data){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making a cross domain request, which is not allowed for security purposes. Either you will have to make a proxy script on your domain (like for example in php) and call yelp from that or fetch the data completely on the server side.

Comment: cross-domain is not an issue.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you must be experiencing part of your data (which you are supposed to see) disappearing. I think you must edit your code to:

```
content = '<p>' + businesses.reviews.text_excerpt + '</p>';
content += '<p>' + businesses.reviews.date + '</p>';
```

Hope this helps...