# Showing JSON in html with javascript

Tags: html, json, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

i am new with JSON. I am using a api which using JSON for response. I am calling the api url by simple xhr method. The code is working and i am getting 200 status but

how do i able to retrieve the JSON in the html?

I was able to show the JSON by printing xhr.responseText in innerHTML. But i need to show the data so i can use them in html.

Can you suggest how i can present the data in html when i have the json data in xhr.responseText.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Can anyone guide me how to do it via jquery also?

Comment: can u please give json response

Comment: Post your current code.  Probably you're trying to return the response, rather than using a callback properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add JSON2.js (from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to your page, then you can parse the JSON into a JavaScript object by using:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

If you completely trust your JSON source, you can also do it very quickly and without using JSON2.js by simply evaling it thus:

```
var parsedData = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
```

but this will run any code embedded in the response and so isn't secure and generally wouldn't be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

here is another post which works and less code because of jquery. The first answer works perfectly. I thought this might be help for people who having same problem.

[Trying to use jQuery to display JSON text data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974929/trying-to-use-jquery-to-display-json-text-data)