# Retreving URL String to generate JSON Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, yelp

I want to access the Yelp API 1.0, I have got for example this URL

> http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=burger&location=Los%20Angeles%2A%20CA&ywsid=SECRETKEY

which will give me some Burger Locations in LA in a JSON String.

How can I access this URL in order turn the response into a JS Object?

I know how to create JS Objects, the problem is getting the response from the server.

Here's my code right now: Maybe we can try to start from there:

```
var url = "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=burger&location=Los%20Angeles%2A%20CA&ywsid=secretKey" ;


            $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                alert("JSON Data: " + json.message.text);
            });
```

Comment: If you can't get $.getJSON to work, you could try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974929/trying-to-use-jquery-to-display-json-text-data/1975080#1975080  But that code looks real ugly to me.

Answer (score 2):

You get into the subject of [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which simply says that you can't reach a URL from **b.com** from **a.com** using ajax in a normal form.

If you use ajax, you should use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), or [Access-Control](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers. Otherwise, you should use your server as a proxy to send regular HTTP GET and POST to that URL.

Comment: Could you provide a basic JSONP or GET example in jQuery/JS?

Answer (score 0):

Add "&callback=myFunction" to the url. Append a script tag to your document with this url as the source.

```
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
```

Then make a function in your page called myFunction, and its first argument will be the data returned.

Comment: I don't understand correcly. Heres my code so far...

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var url = "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=burger&location=Los%20Angeles%2A%20CA&ywsid=asasdasdyyuXSA&callback=myFunction";
 var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
 scriptElem.src = url;
 document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
 
 function myFunction(data){
  
 }
 
</script>

Comment: sure that should work, now you have to put something in myFunction like "console.log(data)" as a start.  However, this code should run AFTER the page has loaded, if you are doing it on page load, just put a script tag in the old fashioned way rather than dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Here's an example using yelp:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=burger&location=Los%20Angeles%2A%20CA&ywsid=SECRETKEY&jsoncallback=?", function(json) {
   console.log("JSON Data: " + json);
});
```

Comment: I tried to use this function, but i couldnt access my URL with it... I got no response

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth I think you need to add `jsoncallback=?` as a query parameter.