# Yelp reviews dont display

Tags: javascript, json, yelp

I am looking at [Trying to use jQuery to display JSON text data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974929/trying-to-use-jquery-to-display-json-text-data) as an example, but I cannot get any information to display.
When I put the url (http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?name=pantibar&term=gay&location=Dublin&limit=1&ywsid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) in chrome postman, it does return the information, but I cannot get it to display on my web page.
Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
function showData(data) {
    $.each(data.businesses, function(i,business){
        // extra loop
        $.each(business.reviews, function(i,review){ 
            var content = '<p>' + review.text_excerpt + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' +review.date + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo('#review');
        });
    });      
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    writeScriptTag( "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?name=pantibar&term=gay&location=Dublin&limit=1&ywsid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 
});

function writeScriptTag(path) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", path);

    document.body.appendChild(fileref);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>



</body>
```

Comment: _"note the use of the "callback" parameter"_ - there is no callback parameter...

Comment: you also don't fire showData() anywhere that I can see? does it automatically get included by the script tag? Don't you have to use ajax to call to the API you show?

Comment: When using the callback, it still does not display anything:
"http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?name=pantibar&term=gay&location=Dublin&limit=1&ywsid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=showData"

Comment: user3036342, could you clarify? I am kind of new to Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to the body and everything worked fine.

```
<div id="review"></div>
```